# Как вытащить значение аргумента value из html элемента что бы сравнить его в assert?

Tags: selenium, test-automation, pytest, value, assertion

Дано автотест сайта https://stellarburgers.nomoreparties.site/register с таким кодом:

```
class RegistrationPage(BasePage):

    reg_locators = RegLocators()

    def registration_with_valid_data(self):
        iterator = next(generate_person_with_valid_data())
        email = iterator.email
        password = iterator.password
        name_of_user = iterator.user_name
        self.element_is_visible(self.reg_locators.NAME_REG).send_keys(name_of_user)
        self.element_is_visible(self.reg_locators.EMAIL_REG).send_keys(email)
        self.element_is_visible(self.reg_locators.PASSWORD_REG).send_keys(password)
        rtr = self.reg_locators.VALUE_EMAIL_REG
        self.element_is_visible(self.reg_locators.BTN_REG).click()
        self.element_is_visible(self.reg_locators.VALUE_EMAIL)
        assert rtr == self.reg_locators.VALUE_EMAIL
```

и такими локаторами

```
class RegLocators:
    # fields
    NAME_REG = (By.XPATH,"//*[@id='root']/div/main/div/form/fieldset[1]/div/div/input")
    EMAIL_REG = (By.XPATH,"//*[@id='root']/div/main/div/form/fieldset[2]/div/div/input")
    PASSWORD_REG = (By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[name = 'Пароль']")
    VALUE_EMAIL_REG = (By.XPATH,"//*[@id='root']/div/main/div/form/fieldset[2]/div/div/input/@value")
    # buttons
    BTN_REG = (By.CSS_SELECTOR,".button_button__33qZ0")
    #to assert
    VALUE_EMAIL = (By.XPATH,"//*[@id='root']/div/main/div/form/fieldset[1]/div/div/input/@value")
    VALUE_PASSWORD = (By.XPATH, "//*[@id='root']/div/main/div/form/fieldset[2]/div/div/input/@value")
```

флоу следующий:
я попадаю на страницу регистрации,
вношу данные,
нажимаю кнопку зарегаться,
попадаю на страницу авторизации где в поле почты и пароля уже введены данные которые я ввел при регистрации.
Так вот я хочу срвнить пароль введенный на странице регистрации через  assert c паролем который отображается на странице авторизации которая открывается после
Введеный пароль сохраняется в атрибут инпута value
я не могу понять как мне вытащить их значение что бы сравнить
Было бы здорово найти ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось в этом отлично помогает .get_attribute('value')
Пример использования:

```
driver.find_element(By.NAME,"пароль").get_attribute('value')
```